# C++ unknown escape sequences on regex + groups captured by half

Tags: c++, regex, url

I'm trying to use the following regex

```
(https?|rtsp):\/\/(?:([^\s@\/]+?)[@])?([^\s\/:]+)(?:[:]([0-9]+))?(?:(\/[^\s?#]+)([?][^\s#]+)?)?([#]\S*)?
```

on C++ like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

int main() {
    std::string str("rtsp://3333:1232@hellowebsite.com:2222");
    std::regex r("(https?|rtsp):\/\/(?:([^\s@\/]+?)[@])?([^\s\/:]+)(?:[:]([0-9]+))?(?:(\/[^\s?#]+)([?][^\s#]+)?)?([#]\S*)?");
    std::smatch m;
    std::regex_search(str, m, r);
    std::cout << str << std::endl;
    for(auto v: m) std::cout << v << std::endl;
  }
```

To match rtsp or http URLs, but this is the output of compilation + running:

```
main.cpp:7:33: warning: unknown escape sequence '\/' [-Wunknown-escape-sequence]
    std::regex r("(https?|rtsp):\/\/(?:([^\s@\/]+?)[@])?([^\s\/:]+)(?:[:]([0-9]+))?(?...
                                ^~
main.cpp:7:35: warning: unknown escape sequence '\/' [-Wunknown-escape-sequence]
    std::regex r("(https?|rtsp):\/\/(?:([^\s@\/]+?)[@])?([^\s\/:]+)(?:[:]([0-9]+))?(?...
                                  ^~
main.cpp:7:43: warning: unknown escape sequence '\s' [-Wunknown-escape-sequence]
    std::regex r("(https?|rtsp):\/\/(?:([^\s@\/]+?)[@])?([^\s\/:]+)(?:[:]([0-9]+))?(?...
                                          ^~
main.cpp:7:46: warning: unknown escape sequence '\/' [-Wunknown-escape-sequence]
    std::regex r("(https?|rtsp):\/\/(?:([^\s@\/]+?)[@])?([^\s\/:]+)(?:[:]([0-9]+))?(?...
                                             ^~
main.cpp:7:60: warning: unknown escape sequence '\s' [-Wunknown-escape-sequence]
    std::regex r("(https?|rtsp):\/\/(?:([^\s@\/]+?)[@])?([^\s\/:]+)(?:[:]([0-9]+))?(?...
                                                           ^~
main.cpp:7:62: warning: unknown escape sequence '\/' [-Wunknown-escape-sequence]
    std::regex r("(https?|rtsp):\/\/(?:([^\s@\/]+?)[@])?([^\s\/:]+)(?:[:]([0-9]+))?(?...
                                                             ^~
main.cpp:7:88: warning: unknown escape sequence '\/' [-Wunknown-escape-sequence]
  ...r("(https?|rtsp):\/\/(?:([^\s@\/]+?)[@])?([^\s\/:]+)(?:[:]([0-9]+))?(?:(\/[^\s?#]+)([...
                                                                             ^~
main.cpp:7:92: warning: unknown escape sequence '\s' [-Wunknown-escape-sequence]
  ...r("(https?|rtsp):\/\/(?:([^\s@\/]+?)[@])?([^\s\/:]+)(?:[:]([0-9]+))?(?:(\/[^\s?#]+)([...
                                                                                 ^~
main.cpp:7:105: warning: unknown escape sequence '\s' [-Wunknown-escape-sequence]
  ...\s#]+)?)?([#]\S*)?");
     ^~
main.cpp:7:118: warning: unknown escape sequence '\S' [-Wunknown-escape-sequence]
  ...\S*)?");
     ^~
10 warnings generated.
 ./main
rtsp://3333:1232@hellowebsite.com:2222
rtsp://3333:1232@helloweb
rtsp
3333:1232
helloweb
```

check [here](https://repl.it/repls/MoccasinTemporalChemistry)..

First of all, why I'm getting unknown escape sequences? `\\`, `\s` and etc are pretty known.

Most importantly, why do I get these unfinished groups? It works fine on regex online testers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Especially when you're doing regexes, raw string literals are your friend. So, as a starting point, I'd do something like this:

```
std::regex r(R"--((https?|rtsp):\/\/(?:([^\s@\/]+?)[@])?([^\s\/:]+)(?:[:]([0-9]+))?(?:(\/[^\s?#]+)([?][^\s#]+)?)?([#]\S*)?)--");
```

If you really don't want to use raw string literals, the starting point is to note that a back-slash in a C++ string introduces an escape sequence, so when you want the literal to actually contain a back-slash you need to use two back-slash characters in a row, so (at bare minimum) you need to convert those, so it starts something like this:

```
std::regex r("(https?|rtsp):\\/\\/(?:
```

...continuing for all the other back-slashes it contains. There might be a bit more to do after that, but that's the minimum that it's immediately obvious you need to do.